# Can anyone remember the name of the library scanning software that uses a virtual flashlight?

Tags: software, library

Hey folks,
  A while ago, I remember hearing about this awesome free software that takes a part of your library, randomly scatters visual dots across your screen, and as you shine a virtual flashlight over them, plays all sounds within the light's radius at the same time. It sounded awesome! But I can't find it, and google isn't helping. Have any of you played with this, and remember the name?

Sorry for the boring question.

Answer (score 4):

Soundtorch!

Cheers

Comment: aww yeaaaaaaaaa